# What are the default numbering settings for the amsplain bibliography style (bibtex)?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, amsart, amsplain

I have a `main.bib` file called  that I am trying to incorporate into an `amsart` document. I orginally had

```
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{main}
```

but I wanted to switch `plain` to `amsplain`. I was under the impression that `amsplain` gives square brackets for bibliography items, but it gave me numbered (1., 2., etc.) instead. Are the default settings for it to be in square brackets? How can I change the nunbering to square brackets? I can't post my code right now as the document is personal, but I will try to make a MWE in another file. In any case, I'm happy with how the rest of `amsplain` format looks, so I really just want a way to change to square brackets.

EDIT: I played around with the code. It seems that using `article` gives the correct output for `amsplain` but if you use `amsmath`, everything is identical except [1] becomes 1. (e.g.). I would have thought that `amsmath` and `amsplain` together would give the desired output, but apparently not. I've seen papers submitted to AMS journals with the desired formatting of both `amsart` and `amsplain` so this should be possible. Any idea how to give square brackets when loading both `amsart` and `amsplain`?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `amsref` will give you square brackets, cf. http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/amscls-doc/Author_Handbook_Journals.pdf:

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{amsrefs}

\begin{document}

Alan Sokal~\cite{Sokal96} recommends Bourbaki’s
text~\cite{Bourbaki70} for a gentle introduction to set theory.

\bibliography{nonsense}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `amsplain` output -- for comparison -- looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

`amsart` defines the default label style for bibliographies thus:

```
\def\@defaultbiblabelstyle#1{#1.}
```

I haven't checked `amsplain.bst` to see if it overrides this, but I suspect it may not.  Therefore, if you put this in your preamble, it should add the brackets you are expecting:

```
\makeatletter
\def\@defaultbiblabelstyle#1{[#1]}
\makeatother
```

Not tested.

Comment: Works with `amsart` + `amsplain`

Comment: @DG' -- Thanks for the confirmation.